# Execute Skaffold deployment using Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, skaffold

I developed the yaml files for kubernetes and skaffold and the dockerfile. My deployment with Skaffold work well in my local machine.

Now I need to implement the same deployment in my k8s cluster in my Google Cloud project, triggered by new tags in a GitHub repository. I found that I have to use Google Cloud Build, but I don't know how to execute Skaffold from the cloudbuild.yaml file.

Answer (score 5):

There is a skaffold image in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community

To use it, follow the following steps:

- Clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community
```

- Go to the skaffold directory

```
cd cloud-builders-community/skaffold
```

- Build the image:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

Then, in your `cloudbuild.yaml`, you can add a step based on this one:

```yaml
- id: 'Skaffold run'
  name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/skaffold:alpha' # https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/skaffold
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=[YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME]'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      gcloud container clusters get-credentials [YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME] --region us-central1-a --project [YAOUR_PROJECT_NAME]
      if [ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" ]
      then
        skaffold run
      fi
```

Comment: so I have to upload that Skaffold image to my cluster before? isn't there any ready to use Skaffold image?

Comment: afaik (and according to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/README.md), you have to push the image to gcr to use one of cloudbuild community images. Of course you also can use any public image from https://hub.docker.com/

Comment: I have another derived question, the docker image listed in this repo wouldn't resolved my issue? https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/releases (gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v1.20.0). Or maybe there is something I'm not seeing. Thanks!

Comment: I never used this image, but it may work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image `gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold`

eg:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.9.0'
  args: ['skaffold', 'build']
```